# Usbmon error - Ubuntu 16.04 with Kernel 4.15 in Dual Boot with Windows 10

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, usb, kernel, permissions

I have some problem in **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with kernel 4.15** in Dual Boot with Windows 10, with a Lenovo T480.
I am trying to get some information from `/sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon/`, but I have some errors. I follow this procedure with **root privileges**:

```
$ sudo modprobe usbmon
$ sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon/0u
```

I obtain the output:

```
cat: /sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon/0u: Operation not permitted
```

The output of `$ sudo ll /sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon` is:

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Sep 26 21:03 ./
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 0 Sep 26 20:48 ../
-rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 26 21:03 0s
-rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 26 21:03 0u
-rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 26 21:03 1s
-rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 26 21:03 1t
-rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 26 21:03 1u
-rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 26 21:03 2s
-rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 26 21:03 2t
-rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 26 21:03 2u
-rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 26 21:03 3s
-rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 26 21:03 3t
-rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 26 21:03 3u
-rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 26 21:03 4s
-rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 26 21:03 4t
-rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 26 21:03 4u
```

Exactly the same error occurs with `$ sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices`. The output is:

```
cat: /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices: Operation not permitted
```

Do you have any idea why I get this weird behavior and how I can solve it?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you check the output of dmesg.

I just ran into this myself, and it turns out it was because of [kernel_lockdown](https://lwn.net/Articles/736910/).

Apparently this locks down various kernel features including debugfs and from what I understand you need to boot without secure boot enabled, to disable it.

Comment: Hi, you are perfectly right. The solution is to disable the secure boot and then everything works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `sudo` powers when looking at some directories and files.

For example:

```
$ cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/uvcvideo/1-7/stats
cat: /sys/kernel/debug/usb/uvcvideo/1-7/stats: Permission denied
```

However with `sudo` powers:

```
$ sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/uvcvideo/1-7/stats
frames:  0
packets: 0
empty:   0
errors:  0
invalid: 0
pts: 0 early, 0 initial, 0 ok
scr: 0 count ok, 0 diff ok
sof: 0 <= sof <= 0, freq 0.000 kHz
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! Unfortunately it does not work. The behaviour does not change. With `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices` I still get the same output: `cat: /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices: Operation not permitted`. Could it be related to some issues with the kernel?